# how do I configure the Ruby auth0 gem to use the Client Key? I keep getting "invalid token"

Tags: auth0

I'm using `auth0` gem version 5.8.0.

I've written an `auth0_client` function based on the one in the [auth0 gem's homepage](https://github.com/auth0/ruby-auth0) and plugged in my app's credentials, but I keep getting:

```
{"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Invalid token","attributes":{"error":"Invalid token"}}
```

This is my function:

```rb
  def auth0_client
    @auth0_client ||= Auth0Client.new(
      client_id: xxx, # value from my app's "Basic Information" page
      client_secret: xxx, # value from my app's "Basic Information" page
      domain: xxx # value from my app's "Basic Information" page
      api_version: 2,
      timeout: 15

      # I don't need this, do I?
      #token: ENV['AUTH0_RUBY_API_TOKEN'],
    )
  end
```

What can possibly be wrong with the credentials that I passed in?  Am I missing something?  What token is invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out that we missed: we didn’t have permissions set for the Management API.

The interface is kind of easy to miss. On the application’s API tab, you need to click the little drop-down arrow on the right to open up the permissions pane:

[image: Screenshot that shows the location of the dropdown button]